# why does set and get functions not work c++?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

i tried to change `cost1` field through `C` class but it didn't work. how can i access and change  `cost1`(inside `M` class) through `C` class.
i am getting null pointer error and it has shown inside `setM` function.

```
class M {
protected:
    int cost1;
public:
    M() {}
    M(int c1) :cost1(c1) {}
    int getCost1() { return cost1; }
    void setCost1(int c1) { cost1 = c1; }

};
```

```
class P {
protected:
    M* _m;
public:
    void setM(M m) {
        _m = &m;
    }
    M getM() {
        return  *_m;
    }
};
```

```
class C {
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<P> _p;
    M _m;
public:
    C(M m) {
        _m = m;
    }
    void setP(std::shared_ptr<P> p) {
        _p = p;
    }
    void applyM() {
        std::cout << _p->getM().getCost1() << std::endl;

        _p->getM().setCost1(11);

        std::cout << _p->getM().getCost1() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<P> p1;
    M m1(5);
    std::shared_ptr<C> c1 = std::make_shared<C>(m1);


    p1->setM(m1);
    c1->setP(p1);
    c1->applyM();

}
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work" what do you mean? Are you getting a compiler error? if so, what is it? If not, what's the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: i am getting a null pointer error.

Comment: `p1` doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger? If not, what development environment are you using? (compiler, IDE, etc.)

Comment: what exactly should i do to fix it

Comment: yes i have access to debugger. null pointer exception has shown inside setM function

Comment: @gakowiw386 *what exactly should i do to fix it* -- Look at `c1`.  What did you do there?

Comment: To fix the issue with `p1` not pointing to anything you can use the same approach as with `c1` (`auto p1 = std::make_shared<P>();`), use `p1.reset(new P());` to manually create an object and put it under control of the smart pointer or pass the new object to the constructor (`std::shared_ptr<P> p1 (new P);`). You should go with the first one btw.

Answer (score 2):

In the following function

```cpp
void setM(M m) {
    _m = &m;
}
```

You are passing `m` by value. This makes a local copy of a passed variable. Then you take address of the copied (local!) variable, which gets destroyed once the function finishes.

You need to pass either by reference or by pointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem in your class `P`. Its constructor takes an `M` object, by value. This means that when it is called, a temporary copy of the caller's `M` object is created and passed to it. The address of this temporary is then stored in the protected member `_m`. After the constructor finishes executing, the temporary copy is destroyed, the `_m` pointer is invalid, and accessing it will cause *undefined behavior*.

The solution is to pass the address that you want to store.

```
class P {
protected:
    M* _m;
public:
    void setM(M* p) {
        _m = p;
    }
    M getM() {
        return  *_m;
    }
};
```

There's also a problem in `main`

```
std::shared_ptr<P> p1;
...
p1->setM(m1);
```

You're dereferencing the pointer `p1` without ever initializing it. Again, this is going to cause *undefined behavior*.